# Performing logarithmic multiple regression with Excel?

Tags: regression, excel

Is it possible to perform logarithmic regression on multiple variables with Excel? If I just have a single independent variable than it's very easy to do this using the best-fit line option (it lets me switch from linear to logarithmic). But this feature does not work for multiple variable regression and the regression feature under the Data Analysis plugin only seems to support linear multiple regression.

However, I have a table that has 3 columns containing 3 independent variables and 1 column with the corresponding dependent variable (outcome). I'm pretty sure there's a logarithmic relationship, but I'm not sure how to use Excel to get the coefficients. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I suggest using a dedicated statistics software, because it is too easy to make mistakes and not be able to recognize that there is a mistake. With a line-based statical software like R, at least you get warned that something is not working, and get a hint, were the mistake might be. Excel will just as likely as not produce some result anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If by logarithmic regression you mean the model `log(y) = m1.x1 + m2.x2 + ... + b + (Error)`, you can use `LOGEST` and `GROWTH` with multiple independent variables. Note that if you want the estimated coefficients `m1, m2, ..., b` from `LOGEST`, you'll have to enter the formula into multiple cells as an array. See Excel's online help for the steps required.

Alternatively, you can log-transform your dependent variable and use `LINEST`/`TREND` which does the same thing under the hood.

ObWarning: Excel isn't the best regression package in the world. See, for example, McCullough & Heiser (2008), On the accuracy of statistical procedures in Microsoft Excel 2007, *Comp Stats & Data Analysis* 52(10) pp.4570-4578.

Comment: +1 Good thorough answer: it provides options and useful comments.